# Avoid using remote identity file when using ssh on remote server

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm connected to `serverA` with SSH. I have one identity file on my local computer, which I use to authenticate to `serverA`, and one identity file on `serverA` which I use when I'm at that computer physically. I have `ForwardAgent yes` in my local ssh config file.

Now, from `serverA`, I'm trying to open another ssh session to `serverB`. However, SSH will then try to use the identity file on `serverA` to connect to `serverB`, but I would like to use the identity file on my local computer (forwarded using ForwardAgent).

How can I tell SSH on `serverA` to use the keys forwarded, instead of the keys on `serverA`, when I am connected to `serverA` through SSH?

**Answer:** The problem, it turned out, was that my local computer was running macOS, which does not add keys to the agent by default. Therefore, no keys were forwarded to serverA. After adding AddKeysToAgent yes as well as ForwardAgent yes to my local config, ssh on the remote linux machine uses the forwarded key instead of the remote key by default. So no changes had to be made to the remote machine.

Comment: Short version, `ssh -i` after copying the _public part_ of your local key to serverA.

Comment: The problem, it turned out, was that my local computer was running macOS, which does not add keys to the agent by default. Therefore, no keys were forwarded to `serverA`. After adding `AddKeysToAgent yes` as well as `ForwardAgent yes` to my local config, ssh on the remote linux machine uses the forwarded key instead of the remote key by default. So no changes had to be made to the remote machine.